# How to index and search on a binary type (docx file) with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, base64, oracle-apex

I have an oracle Apex app.
I have a blob column in a table, which I'm indexing with Elastic search (using blob2base64 to convert the content of docx files when indexing them) but when trying to search on this base64 field, I get nothing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Then please [edit] the question to include a [mre].